How to identify points in a Bitmap and compute distance between in C#?
Using VS2022.  Trying to understand Machine Learning and processing of an image.  Created a bitmap in MS Paint, with 3 small circles, filled in with black color, to simulate 3 points on a map.
In one example it said the .bmp must be first converted to SVG.
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //save the file to new fmt
            // Initialize an instance of the ImageVectorizer class
            var vectorizer = new ImageVectorizer
            {
                //optionally set configuration
                Configuration =
                {
            //optionally set path builder
            PathBuilder = new BezierPathBuilder {
            //optionally set trace smoother
            TraceSmoother = new ImageTraceSmoother(1),
                ErrorThreshold =  30,
                MaxIterations = 30
            },
            ColorsLimit = 25,
            LineWidth = 1
                }
            };
            // Vectorize BMP from the specified file
            using var document = vectorizer.Vectorize(@"c:\users\umtilli\pictures\testr.bmp");
            // Save vectorized BMP image as SVG file 
            document.Save(@"c:\users\umtilli\pictures\mage.svg");


        }


Ok, this worked.  Have a standard WinForms project. I can display the BMP in a picturebox, but the SVG throws an exception.  Searched and brought in Aspose in NuGet.

 //// System.Drawing.Graphics G = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1);
      Image rr = new System.Drawing.Image....



But can't use any of it, Compiler Error CS0433, Aspose and Microsoft.System both have type Graphics.
Ironing this out, but maybe there is a better way? Hoping for a C# project, open a bitmap with 3 or 4 dots, and do Machine Learning that will do processing, and outline the dots, and show distance, etc. It is not homework.
I have searched online for days, tried numerous examples, signed up to Udemy and tried to find this kind of processing, there is calculus and ML, but its not in C#.  Have not found a working example. Expecting to write something in a winForm that has an open file dialog, pick a .bmp, do the conversion if needed to SVG (this I can do), and then draw circles. Or polygons around the dots and measure them.  I don't know if the software will know that its a bitmap image of 800 x 1000 and know the size. I picked this as something I should be able to do in code.

Looks like you are trying to implement some machine learning to recognize image patterns? Since you mentioned Aspose.SVG, are you facing any issues while vectorizing the image? If possible, can you please create a post in our dedicated support forum with some sample files and requirement details? We will further proceed you accordingly. Please note that our dedicated forums are right place to discuss requirements about Aspose APis. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.
